# C++ inheritance inside template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Inheritance of class seems to work oddly inside a template class

```
template<typename T>
class b
{
public:
    class base
    {
    public:
        int a = 2;
    };

    class A : public base
    {
    public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout << a << endl;
        }
    };
};
```

When this piece of code is compiled, compiler would regard a as not declared(in A::fun())
However, if you write `this->a` instead of a, everything is ok

Question is: why won't the compiler interpret a as `this->a`(as it does in normal class)

Comment: Nice example. It isn't immediately clear why `base::a` is dependent. But one must remember that it's actually `b<T>::base::a`. And, `b<T>::base` [may be specialized separately!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ab98d823f022968).